# Disable Importing of Documents and Settings during install?

Tags: system-installation

I like to dual-boot most of my machines with Windows 7 and the latest version of Ubuntu. I main Ubuntu of course, but I keep a standard Windows install for games, and for Visual Studio for work and development.

The trouble is, every time I install Ubuntu fresh (which I like to do for every new version, as I enjoy setting things up new each time) the installer copies all of my documents and folders over from my Windows partition, which is often a LOT of files, that I of course immediately delete once I'm logged into Ubuntu the first time. It also (amusingly, in an ironic way) copies the desktop wallpaper, which is the giant blue windows logo.

This is really more of an inconvenience than anything, but is there any way to disable this behavior? I didn't see anything about it as an option while setting up the installer, and it really seems like there should be an option about that somewhere. Also, I'm curious as to what "Settings" get imported. What all do I need to run around and undo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04, this is an option.

Image: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Partitions13-600x427.png
From guide: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run the installer by

```
gksudo ubiquity --no-migration-assistant
```